# Vue + DRF No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vue-router, cors

Имею API, которое по запросам 
http://localhost:8000/api/vacancies/ - выводит все вакансии списком
http://localhost:8000/api/vacancies/3/ - выводит конкретную вакансию
работает как в браузере (вывод от DRF), так и в Postman

Что примечательно: первый запрос - прекрасно отрабатывается vue вот так:

```js
fetch(link, {
    method: "get"
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(jsonData => {
    this.results = jsonData;
  });
```

где link - ссылка

Я делаю ссылку для vue-router, передаю туда id, нужной вакансии, vue открывает новый шаблон, показывает, что он получил параметр, сгенерировал ссылку вида http://localhost:8000/api/vacancies/3/ правильно, но вместо результата выдаёт ошибку

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

и

net::ERR_FAILED

Для выполнения запроса использую тот же код, что и в 1 случае
Почему не отрабатывает запрос?

[image: В интерфейсе DRF]

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась установкой

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cross-domain-cors/mjhpgnbimicffchbodmgfnemoghjakai/related?hl=ru

решилась частично - данные получаются и отображаются, но ошибки в консоль летят

Answer (score 0):

Можно запустить `Google Chrome` с параметрами отключения безопасности

`--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\pathToNewFolder"`

Перез запуском необходимо отключить все рабочие процессы `Google Chrome`

Данный способ подходит, если вы тестируете ваше приложение и сервер API находиться на разных портах.

Другой вариант, состоит в том чтобы сервер API отправлял ответ клиенту с заголовком `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

[Об заголовке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: тут прикол в том, что проблема с CORS, только на одном типе запроса, вывод списка постранично работал нормально (Django cors настройка была)

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто еще борется с этой проблемой, вот простой гайд, который может вам помочь.

1. Устаналиваем пакет django-cors-headers (pip install django-cors-headers)
2. Добавляем в INSTALLED_APPS = ['corsheaders',]
3. Добавялем в MIDDLEWARE = ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',]
4. Устанавливаем флажок в settings.py CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
   После этого запускаем сервер и все должно работать.

ВАЖНО!!! На продакшн серверы такое писать не нужно, т.к. не безопасно, но в своих или учебных проектах это может вам помочь.